# What was with the beggar in Mr Nobody?

Tags: character, mr-nobody

In Mr. Nobody, In Anna's version of the story, it shows a woman beggar twice. Once when Nemo gives him money and second when she dies. I never understood these scenes' importance much. First I thought she was one of his other love but her face and hair doesn't match with Elise or Jeanne. So who was she and what's her importance in the story. Is there some deleted scene for her story or am I over-thinking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the clock in both the scenes, it'll lead to the answer.

Nemo passes through the pathway everyday at 9:10
Anna passes through the pathway everyday at 9:20

That's why they never meet (Although they feel the presence of each other in some way).

Now the death of that beggar makes nemo to stay in the pathway till 9:20, anna passes through the pathway as usual at 9:20 , and ta-da they meet.

Comment: Didn't noticed that.